# Installshield internal build error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

Seeking wisdom as i feel as if i am banging my head against wall here, have already spent far too long on what i feel should be a straight forward task. I am using VS2012 to build c# app and trying build an .exe using  installshield 2013 installed also. Each time i attempt to do so i get an ISEXP internal build error.

It is worth noting that i am restricted with my environment as i am unable to access the internet, so i have had to manually get the prerequisite's put on my machine is there a way of getting the VS to point at these now that they are stored locally and don't have to be downloaded? Could this be causing the internal error?

Many Thanks

Comment: "have already spent far too long on what i feel should be a straight forward task" - I can relate - that sums up my experience with InstallShield as well, unfortunately.

Comment: InstallShield is the absolute pits of installers. It's 2016, and InstallShield hasn't caught up from the 90's. 

It's just a miracle they're still in business.

Answer (score 1):

*InstallShield* errors (ISEXP) are caused by a myriad of faults.
I have gone through a lot myself.

Are you using *InstallShield Express*? If so. 
Then make that a double myriad of faults. :)

Some of the things you should make sure you have done:

1. Defined correctly all icons at *each* step (yes, it is that sensitive)
2. Defined correctly all the prerequisites (*.prq files) and make sure that they exist
3. Make sure your projects are building.
4. Make sure that the targets are correct.

Comment: It is as i feared there could be numerous things wrong when,  I will have to step through the isproj again to check the above.

Comment: @DeveloperRB: another thing that worked for me: restart Visual Studio.  It's annoying that this actually solved the problem since it doesn't shed any light on the problem, but at least it keeps oneself from damaging one's walls with one's head.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough rep to add a comment, I'll just post this here - restarting visual studio also worked for me to resolve this error in InstallShield Limited Edition.